# PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 16): Making a list and checking it

Tags: knowledge, pattern, seasonal, connect-wall

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2023](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7527). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd><Previous Door</kbd>](/q/124680)[<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](/q/124699)</sub>

---

Lots of last minute flurry in the S household! I needed to come up with a Christmas-themed puzzle in a hurry. Fortunately, my ever-reliable spouse handed me a list labelled "last minute" and I was able to construct the following puzzle.

Divide into groups:-

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ANDERLECHT | BATMAN | BOAT | BRING | BROWNING | COUCH |
| DANVERS | DOWN | DREAMS | HORSEHAIR | HOT | IMPERATOR |
| ISTANBUL | LINGER | NANTES | NOW | POLYFILL | RWDM |
| SEED | TRAIN | UNION | US | VAN | ZOMBIE |

Do you think that they'll be pleased with this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Oh dear, you're in trouble - and...

> ...you're going to go hungry.

The 'last minute' list you were handed probably said something like the following:

> Turkey
>  Potatoes
>  Carrots
>  Brussels
>  Gravy
>  Stuffing
>  Cranberries
>  Some figgy pudding

Because...

> ...this is a shopping list for your family Christmas dinner!

You have constructed this puzzle by...

> ...creating a connecting wall with three items corresponding to each list entry:
>
>  **Group 1: Cities in Turkey:** [BATMAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman,_Turkey), ISTANBUL, [VAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van,_Turkey)
>
>  **Group 2: _____ Potatoes:** COUCH Potatoes, HOT Potatoes, [SEED Potatoes](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seed%20potato)
>
>  **Group 3: Carrot [cultivars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot#Cultivars):** DANVERS, IMPERATOR, NANTES
>
>  **Group 4: Football teams from the Brussels region:** [ANDERLECHT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.S.C._Anderlecht), [RWDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RWDM), [UNION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royale_Union_Saint-Gilloise)
>
>  **Group 5: Gravy _____**: BOAT, [BROWNING](https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/gravy_browning), TRAIN
>
>  **Group 6: Materials used for 'stuffing' soft furnishings or upholstery:** [DOWN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_feather), [HORSEHAIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horsehair), [POLYFILL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyester_fiberfill)
>
>  **Group 7: Songs by [The Cranberries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cranberries_discography):** DREAMS, LINGER, ZOMBIE
>
>  **Group 8: Words that precede 'some figgy pudding' in the Christmas carol, [*We Wish You A Merry Christmas*](https://genius.com/Christmas-songs-we-wish-you-a-merry-christmas-lyrics):** NOW BRING US (some figgy pudding)

Hopefully my message here has arrived to you in time to rectify your mistake. (Next time, follow Santa's example and check your lists twice...) Now go, go, go!

Comment: Almost perfect. Try reordering the last group.

Comment: good work. i was convinced it was two in each group, given the title... checking it.. twice! great answer Stiv

Comment: @DanielS Ah, that was my other thought - should have gone with it from the start! Thanks for a nice morning mental runaround :)

Comment: @Stiv ... and that's a wrap (as a minor note rot13([cbylsvyy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyester_fiberfill) vf hfrq gb fghss cvyybjf naq phqqyl gblf). Now, you must excuse me; I have an urgent errand...

Comment: @DanielS Oh, I hadn't come across that one before - will amend :)